# Как добавить событие при изменении QTimeEdit и, как изменить значение QTimeEdit PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, сигналы-слоты, qtimeedit

У меня есть `QTimeEdit`, мне надо при изменении значения вызывать функцию `test_func()`.

И как я могу изменять значение `QTimeEdit` по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте код, который вы уже написали.

> void QDateTimeEdit::[**timeChanged**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatetimeedit.html#timeChanged)(QTime time)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда изменяется время.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *                     # установите свои имплрты для PySide2


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()   
        
        self.timeEdit = QTimeEdit(QTime.currentTime())   
        self.timeEdit.setDisplayFormat('HH:mm:ss')
        self.timeEdit.timeChanged.connect(self.time_changed)

        self.button = QPushButton('Увеличить время на 5 минут')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        self.layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.layout.addRow(QLabel('timeChanged'), self.timeEdit)
        self.layout.addRow('', self.button)

    def time_changed(self, time):
        print(f'Time Changed: {time} --> {time.toString("hh:mm:ss")}')
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        _time = self.timeEdit.time()                      # получить время
        print(f'\nTime         : {_time}')
        _time = _time.addSecs(60 * 5)                     # изменить время
        print(f'Time + 5 мин.: {_time}')
        self.timeEdit.setTime(_time)                      # установить новое время
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А есть способ, чтобы можно было установить значение, по нажатию на кнопку устанавливалось 15.00?

Comment: @ВаняДюльгер   `self.timeEdit.setTime(QTime(15,0,0))` . Пожалуйста, если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[Вот сигнал (timeChanged)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.timeChanged) получения измененного значения времени

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.te = QTimeEdit(self)

        self.te.timeChanged.connect(self.timeChanged)

    def onTimeChanged(self, time):
        print(time.toString("HH.mm.ss"))
```

[Вот слот (setTime)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.setTime) для установки нового значения времени

```
    self.timeEdit.setTime(<QTime>)
```